# setdata() and column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Highchart and I want set data but  SetData() not working on a column chart.

I found questions here talking about the same problem I have, but I can't find the solution.

Here is my code source :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" style="width:200px">

$(function () {
       var x = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9]

            }]
        });

$("#button").click( function()
           {
             x.series[0].setData(30);
           }
      );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/foxgenki/Nf2xb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you [haven't looked hard enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417601/using-highcharts-setdata-for-multiple-variables):

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    x.series[0].setData([30]);
});
```

`setData` accepts a list as a parameter, not a number.